# Xamarin : Application not installed issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When I install my application in debugging mode on my Android mobile device, it seems to be installed.

However, after signing the application and publishing it, it's not installed on my phone. (Release mode)

It says: Application not installed.
I tried a few things but cannot resolve this problem. I also tested with another Keystore but it still cannot be installed.

I verified Xamarin Studio options but everything is OK, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: have you tried this after Project clean as it might be packaging issue?

Answer (score 17):

The correct process of creating apk is given below

1. First change your build type to Release from debug.
2. Clean
3. Rebuild
4. Right click your android project and click on archive
5. After successful archive click on Distribute and click on Ad-hoc
6. Create keystore file
7. After finishing click on Open Distribution
   Your apk file is ready.

Comment: Is "Rebuild" after "Clean" really necessary?

Comment: Rebuild includes Clean, so actually Clean is not necessary in this case.

Comment: This is perfect, I was struggling with this "Not installed" problem for quite sometime. I tried manually `signing` & `zipalign` and none of it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late in party. But I believe it could help someone to resolve his issue.

Sometimes the issue is unsupported Architecture.

You can resolve it by

> *Android Project>Properties>Android Options> Advance>Supported Architecture*.

Here you can check the supported architecture according to your device and the issue would be resolved. (I believe app should support maximum of architectures so check them all).

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 1):

For OS X and windows the commands are same:

For windows please download: MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015

For release version (the actual problem you are facing): type in command tool:

```
 msbuild /p:Configuration=Release Path\To\Your\ApplicationProject.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't explain your problem I would post directly on [their forums](http://forums.xamarin.com) or contact their support. That could also help if you could find the installation log, there is probably an explanation why it fails to install.

Comment: @user3638329 Oops, you're right, well, then you should easily have an install log, what does it says? Anything else before the Application not installed?

Comment: @user3638329 What do you mean you cannot see any error. There is nothing shown in the Output window? Are you user Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/72399/#Comment_72399.

The answer from Felix Alcala works perfect. No more "App not installed" messages on device.

Open the SDK Locations in Xamarin Studio

> Preferences/Projects/SDK Locations/Android

and set Java SDK(JDK) to

> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Finally, generate the .apk file again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target sdk when debug and check version of your android device.

Version of android device should be equal or greater than the target sdk in debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play scans the device for threats before installing anything from unknown source. When you try to install for the first time, it will ask if you want to install, if you let it install it'll work fine. But second time, even if it asks or not, it won't let you install. One solution for this is, go to your play store, under Play Protect disable ' scan device for security threats' and then install it, it should work! One other reason for the error could be that app is already installed in your device, uninstall the app or change the signature and then try to install it, It should work! If these don't work, try to debug through usb, adb would show you the error and then you can work on that!

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter this issue if you have installed then uninstalled the same app from your phone.

In Visual Studio, go to

> Tools > Android > Android Adb Command Prompt

Ensure your phone is connected and debugging is enabled on your phone. If this is done properly, the name of your phone should show in Visual Studio next to the run button.

In the adb command prompt, enter this command:

> adb uninstall [your package name]

E.g.

> adb uninstall com.mypackage

You should then be able to install your APK

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me, after downloading the .apk from my android device browser and pressing the Install button, it said "App not installed" with no further information. After downloading it several times, (each time getting the same issue) I finally got the message that I could not download de .apk because I did not have enough storage in my device. So, check if you have enough storage in your phone before trying to install it, as the error message is only "App not installed" instead of warning that there is not enough space.