# Why does the error "App not installed" appear on Android device? Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, arm, apk, abi

I have archived the apk file (release mode) and move it to my device, when trying to install error "App not installed" appear.

Doing the same but in debug mode installation goes fine, but when I open it just gets stuck in the splash screen.

I tried this with two Android devices, one has the Android 11 version and the other 8.1.
Also checked the architectures and all options are selected, as per default.

[image: arquitectures]

Update:
using x86_64 alone (debug) the apk works in the emulator, doesnt get installed in Android 11 nor 8.1
using x86_64 alone (release) in the emulator gets stuck in splash screen

using v7a or v8a alone (debug) gets installed in Android 11 and 8.1, but doesn't go beyond splash screen
using v7a alone (release) Android 11, shows message `App not installed.`
using v8a alone (release) Android 11, shows message `App not installed.`

This are the logs when the App not installed part: https://pastebin.com/R1ZcGHMR

When deploying this app in release mode to the emulator, which is x86_64 does work fine. But if I drag and drop the apk file and install it in the emulator happens the same as in the physical devices.

Could something be going wrong with the archiving?

Comment: are you seeing any error in logcat?

Comment: Try debugging in the real device & get the error log, must be some xaml key issue.

Comment: @DinkarKumar yes, I updated the question

Comment: @TechyHernández Maybe you can try to enable MultiDex  Property in Android options.

Comment: IIRC, there are two different ways to build an APK. One (old) way creates a separate APK for each architecture; the other (newer) way creates a single APK containing all architectures. The message sounds like its not an APK for that device architecture. Are you sure there isn't a different APK, in a sub-folder? I haven't been building recently, but I remember for testing changing some build option temporarily (to the old way) to make the single large APK file, so it would work everywhere.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve as I understand I'm doing it "the old way" meaning has all architectures selected and only created one apk file.
I have also tried selecting only v7a or v8a and creating the apk to my Android 11 device, but doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you create “signed APK” by selecting “Ad hoc” [as shown in picture here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#archive-for-publishing)? Scroll down to section “Distribution“. Only “signed” apks can be installed on a physical device, for security reasons.

Comment: First solve App not installed, hopefully following instructions for signed apk works. Then getting stuck on splash screen is a different problem. That means it fails to load main page. Either a missing resource or an error in code that runs to display that page. Not sure why it would fail only in release mode. Must be some error message in log. Test with a very simple main page, get that to work first.

Comment: It fails only in release mode AND from the APK. If I deploy in release mode to the device (physical or emulator) works fine.

Comment: @TechyHernández From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871222/xamarin-application-not-installed-issue), try to follow the step that creating apk